# Groovy/Java regex to separate json names and values in two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

Below sample shows some name and value pair of a json file. In real life I have over 300 name and value pair for the json file where each name is different. SO I thought of getting the names in one array using regex and values in another. 
I've reviewed many other questions like this but can't make a head or tail out of them.

what I need is:
I need 2 regular expressions for this piece of JSON.
I want to capture the names with one regex and values with another regex.
The names should include: roleId status seq item1 item2 ... ghost and values should include: 43322  841-1 ... null. NOTICE I left out comma intentionally because I don't want it. Also notice that the last value has no comma.

BTW, I'm using jsonslurper in soapui to parser this json.

I don't if there's any other way I can do it besides regex. Anything will be ok as long as I don't have to type each name to get the value like productDetails[0].roleId which returns 43322. I will have to write over 300 of them.

```
{
  "productDetails": [{
        "roleId": 43322,
        "status": "",
        "seq": "841-1",
        "item1": "Yellow",
        "item2": "green",
        "majorColor": "Black",
        "srs": "abc",
        "additionalBrightness": null,
        "isThisNull": null,
        "burned": null,
        "ghost": null
  }]}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Since this is a JSON file, can't you just read it with javascript and capture only the values you want? Loop through as many elements there are and extract only the keys / values you need. No need for regex.

Comment: you could also look at something like [`Object.keys(productDetails[0]).join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values(productDetails[0]).join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: JsonSlurper is the easyest way to parse json. And 300 key-value pairs is not a big deal for JsonSlurper... productDetails[0] will be parsed to Map. productDetails[0].keySet() will return all names..